# How to retrieve messages from a given date using Jsonb?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (tbl_id int, messages jsonb);
CREATE INDEX index_tbl ON tbl USING gin (messages);
```

And the JSON messages as array:

```
[{"user_id":1,"created_at":"2016-12-20","content":"Suspendisse accumsan tortor quis turpis. Sed ante."},
 {"user_id":2,"created_at":"2016-12-20","content":"Morbi sem mauris tibulum sagittis sapien."},
 {"user_id":1,"created_at":"2016-10-21","content":"In blandit ultrices enim. Phasellus id sapien in sapien iaculis congue."},
 {"user_id":3,"created_at":"2016-11-20","content":"Quisque ut erat. Curabitur gravida nisi at nibh. In hac habitasse platea dictumst."},
 {"user_id":4,"created_at":"2016-12-21","content":"Nunc rhoncus dui vel sem. Sed sagittis. ectus. Pellentesque at nulla. Suspendisse potenti. Cras in purus eu magna vulputate luctus."},
 {"user_id":6,"created_at":"2016-12-21","content":"Praesent id massa id nisl venenatis lacinia. iaculis congue."}]
```

How can I select the messages where the user is in only one month?
For example, users of the month of December only return me the messages of users 2, 4 and 6 because user 1 is in the month of November as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This returns all ..

> messages where the user is in only one month

```
WITH msg AS (
   SELECT tbl_id
        ,(msg->>'user_id')::int                                      AS user_id
        , date_trunc('month', (msg->>'created_at')::timestamp)::date AS created_month
        , msg->>'content'                                            AS content
   FROM   tbl t, jsonb_array_elements(t.messages) msg
   )
SELECT m.*
FROM  (
   SELECT user_id
   FROM   msg 
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(DISTINCT created_month) = 1
   ) u
JOIN msg m USING (user_id);
```

1. Unnest the JSON array with [`jsonb_array_elements()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE).
2. Extract values for relevant keys. Only the month of the date is relevant, use [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) and cast the result back to `date`.
3. Run the actual query on the CTE `msg` resulting from step *1.* and *2.* Identify users that posted in only one month - across the whole table, not just within one row. You did not clarify, I chose this interpretation.
4. Self-join to the same CTE `msg` to return all messages of identifies users.

The GIN index is not going to help, since you need to inspect every single array element either way.

Storing messages in a normalized table to begin with would be simpler and faster for your query:

```
message (user_id int, created_at date, content text)
```

Comment: Hey man, thanks for your response. It worked perfectly. True, I'm thinking of creating a normalized table. The query will take a long time when more records are available.

Comment: If I want to filter for a specific month how can I do? 

'SELECT m.*
FROM  (
   SELECT sender
   FROM   msg
   WHERE created_month = date_trunc('month', '2016-12-20'::timestamp)::date
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING count(DISTINCT created_month) = 1
   ) u
JOIN msg m USING (sender);'